# I am trying to update a column of a table of a database from a column of different table of different database

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update table1
set table1.col1=(select t2.c2 as X from t2@dblink)
where t1.c2=(select t3.c3,t3.c4,t3.c5 from t3@dblink)
```

but i am getting

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

can someone help me out with this.

Comment: You need correlated subqueries.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The error is obvious.  How to fix it, much less so.

Comment: The sub query is returning many records. So here i need to update a column of a table from different different table based on a particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

As you were told, sample data would help, as well as posting consistent information (you are updating TABLE1 and, later, use T1 which is ... what?).

Anyway, something like this might give you an idea:

```
update table1 t1 set
  t1.c1 = (select t2.c2 
           from t2@dblink t2
           where t2.some_column = t1.some_column  --> you miss this
          )
where t1.cs in (select t3.c3 from t3@dblink union
                select t3.c4 from t3@dblink union
                select t3.c5 from t3@dblink
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem:

Your subquery is returning multiple records and you are checking equality with a single value.

```
value1 <> {v2,v3,v4,v5,....}
```

you need to use the in clause (with a union if you intend to compare t1,cs with multiple columns on t2)